# Connecting to a remote docker registry over DirectAccess

Tags: docker

My company uses DirectAccess to connect my laptop at home to corporate network assets, e.g. file shares, intranet sites etc. I cannot log in to our docker registry from my laptop over Direct Access but can on my LAN connected desktop in the office. Network engineers have confirmed that the traffic is not being blocked, it is tunnelled to the LAN as internal traffic. A suggestion was that Docker is at some point using the IP address of the server instead of the server name, which will fail as DirectAccess tunnels internal traffic over IPv6 (these are the details as explained to me, might be inaccurate!)

```
PS C:\src> docker login dockerrelease.initech.com
Username: jsmith1
Password:
Error response from daemon: Get https://dockerrelease.initech.com/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Comment: Is registry start with https or http?

Comment: Have you restarted docker after connecting to the VPN?

Comment: @full_steak_developer The registry is https

Comment: @nonpoliticaltag add your  registry in /etc/docker/daemon.json file